# Localizar registro no MySQL por caractere específico

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma banco chamado `completo`, cuja tabela `dados` é:

```
        id  cpf          nome
         1  38831370570  joao da silva
         2  27283620508  maria joaquina
         3  94470661945  carlos eduardo
```

Gostaria de 'Filtrar' todos CPFs q contenham determinado dígito na nona posicao, com base nisto:

> "Para determinar em qual estado brasileiro um CPF foi emitido, é necessário obter o último algarismo do CPF, ignorando os dois dígitos de controle / verificadores. Um exemplo de como determinar este número é o CPF nº XXX.XXX.XX6-XX. Em destaque vemos o último número válido do CPF, ignorando os dígitos verificadores."

Quero buscar no banco todos CPFs do Rio de Janeiro, por exemplo, de acordo com esta relação:

```
 1. Distrito Federal, Goiás, Mato Grosso do Sul e Tocantins;
 2. Pará, Amazonas, Acre, Amapá, Rondônia e Roraima;
 3. Ceará, Maranhão e Piauí;
 4. Pernambuco, Rio Grande do Norte, Paraíba e Alagoas;
 5. Bahia e Sergipe;
 6. Minas Gerais;
 7. Rio de Janeiro e Espírito Santo;
 8. São Paulo;
 9. Paraná e Santa Catarina;
 10.Rio Grande do Sul.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai usar `SUBSTRING`, que retorna um número especifico de caracteres.

No exemplo abaixo adiciono o `SUBSTRING(cpf,9,1)`, que vai retornar o nono caractere e vai comparar com o número do estado desejado:

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE SUBSTRING(cpf,9,1) = '8'
```

No exemplo acima, serão retornados os CPFs de São Paulo. Você troca o número 8 pelo número do estado que você quiser.

Comment: Grato Amigo Me ajudou

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo qual erro está retornando ?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo que bizarro, Oo agora eu to confuso, será que o cara me positivou errado?

Comment: E @LeoCaracciolo sua resposta está incorreta, ele quer o 9° digito sendo o numero do estado, o seu está puxando o ultimo, o 11°. Vou abrir no banco aqui.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo O seu não está retornando nada porque não existe nenhum digito '8' na nona posição em nenhum dos registros da sua tabela :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Porque tem número '8' na 11° posição, mas o correto é ter na nona, o seu está certo, basta por "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE SUBSTRING(cpf,9) = '8'"

Comment: É , ai depende do digito que você por, se colocar "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE SUBSTRING(cpf,9) = '5'" no seu banco vai retornar resultados pq existe '5' na nona posição.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Você tem razão, vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Estava confundindo com a substring do Javascript também... mas obrigado pela correção.

Comment: A resposta agora está correta, fica sempre a sugestão de complementar com um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) para valorizar a resposta com uma demonstração.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função [**MID**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/gg251677.aspx) que retorna um número especificado de caracteres de uma string, dados uma posição e um comprimento iniciais.

```
 SELECT * FROM dados where MID(cpf,9,1) = 7;
```

Lista com 8 CPFs de exemplo

[image: Lista com 8 CPFs de exemplo]

Resultado da query, mostrando apenas CPFs cuja 9ª posição é igual a 7:

[**No SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a518/1)

No meu servidor:

[image: Resultado da query, mostrando apenas CPFs cuja nona posição é 7]

Outra opção é a função   [**substr**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)    `SELECT * FROM dados where substr(cpf,-3,1) = 7;`  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec08/2)

Comment: Grato Amigo Me ajudou